# gcc not found by win-builder

Tags: r, windows, gcc

I've built an R package which includes C/C++ code. I am now trying to test this package on [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/). Unfortunately, the following error is returned in `00install.out`:

```
* installing *source* package 'mypackage' ...
** libs
  running 'src/Makefile.win' ...
/usr/bin/make --directory=lib/mylib/
gcc -g -Wall -fPIC -c mycode.c
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [mycode.o] Error 127
make: *** [mylib] Error 2
Warning: running command 'make --no-print-directory -f "Makefile.win"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mypackage'
* removing 'd:/RCompile/CRANguest/R-release/lib/mypackage'
```

Trying with `gcc`, `gcc.exe`, and `cc` yielded similar results.

Accordingly, I set up a testing environment on a Windows virtual machine according to [these instructions](https://www.biostat.wisc.edu/~kbroman/Rintro/Rwinpack.html). Running `R CMD INSTALL .` on the code from the command line within this environment resulted in the code compiling and the package installing without issue. (Running `R CMD build .` also yielded no errors.)

What's up with win-builder, and how can I achieve compilation on it?

Or, more importantly, is being able to build the package on Windows sufficient, regardless of whether it worked on win-builder?

My `Makefile.win` is as follows:

```
export CCOMP = gcc
export CPPCOMP = c++
export ADD_CC_FLAGS = -O3
APP_DIR = ./apps/myapp
LIB_DIR = ./lib/mylib

.PHONY: all $(APP_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)

all: $(APP_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)

$(APP_DIR) $(LIB_DIR): mylib
  $(MAKE) --directory=$@

$(APP_DIR): $(LIB_DIR) mylib

mylib:
  $(MAKE) --directory=lib/mylib
```

Inserting `echo %PATH%` into the make file under the `mylib` target yielded:

```
Makefile.win:24: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Comment: Can you include your Makefile.win content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an obscure error here because you included a file `Makefile.win`.

But the semantics of `make`, if such a file is found, it will be used ... which is **not** what you want here.  R builds **its own** `Makefile.win` and you are supposed to only supply a snippet to be included -- which **must** be called `Makevars.win`.

That is rule number one.  Rules number two is to not included all the material you would include in a `Makefile` -- as you would clobber what R already brings to the table.  All this is in *Writing R Extensions* but could of course be clearer.

My pragmatic suggestion: take a package you know and like which has a working R build in win-builder, and modify it.  You can test locally should you have access to an R system with Rtools etc pp.

---

**Edit from OP**:

I needed to compile an executable which relied on several libraries. The library codes were in `src/libs` and the executable's code was in `src/apps`. I ensured that running `make` within each subdirectory worked and set `src/apps/Makefile` to use relative paths to pull in the results of `src/libs`. The only problem then, was getting the whole chain running. To do so, I created a file `src/Makevars.win` which had the following structure:

```
.PHONY: all myprogram sublib1 sublib2

all: sublib1 sublib2 myprogram

myprogram: sublib1 sublib2
  @(cd apps/myprogram && $(MAKE) CXX="$(CXX)" CC="$(CC)" CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS)" AR="$(AR)" RANLIB="$(RANLIB)")

sublib1:
  @(cd lib/sublib1    && $(MAKE) CXX="$(CXX)" CC="$(CC)" CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS)" AR="$(AR)" RANLIB="$(RANLIB)")

sublib2:
  @(cd lib/sublib2    && $(MAKE) CXX="$(CXX)" CC="$(CC)" CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) $(CPICFLAGS)" AR="$(AR)" RANLIB="$(RANLIB)")
```

As I understand it, `Makevars.win` gets embedded in a dynamically generated `Makefile` that R produces. So, `$(CC)` is actually referencing this hidden code.

(There are probably more clever ways to do this.)

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed the case that *Writing R Extensions* could be clearer. I've looked at another package I like (`dplyr`) and it seems the code is considerably simpler than mine. My `makefile` recursively calls to six different subdirectories, which have their own makefiles. These produce static libraries which are then assemebled into an executable. I am not sure how to capture that with `Makevars`, though perhaps that is a separate question.

Comment: It's hard. Some packages do this -- and some others farm this out to `configure` and `configure.win`.

Comment: Reading [this link](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_14.html#SEC14) now.

Comment: Using `Makevars.win` and `Makevars` was most certainly the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know!  If you have a good solution for building dependent packages / libraries from `Makevars`, it might be worth a blog post or similar... as this really is not that obvious or well-documented.

Comment: I've edited your answer to include a brief description of what I did; hope you don't mind.

Comment: No, that I don't mind as you were polite enough to mark your edits--this is in fact a good idea, so thanks!